# Syntax highlighting not working for Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 version 16.9.4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Syntax highlighting for javascript files has never worked for me in Visual Studio 2019 from the beginning.  I am on version 16.9.4 but previous versions did not work either.  I am not using the Resharper extension which I heard can interfere with syntax highlighting.  All of my extension are up to date:

- Liquid Studio
- Live Share
- Wix v3 - Visual Studio 2019 Extension
- Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools
- Test Adapter for Boost.Test
- Visual Studio IntelliCode
- Cloud Explorer for VS 2019 Preview
- Web Live Preview (Preview)
- Microsoft Library Manager
- NuGetRecommender [Preview]
- Visual Studio Rich Navigation [Preview]
- Test Adapter for Google Test
- Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for Javascript

These are the tools I have:
[image]